# Jupyter Notebook install breaks sqlite3

Tags: python, jupyter

Using the following code, I install a dedicated conda environment:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify no
conda create --name kmkplot
conda activate kmkplot
conda install -c plotly plotly=4.0.0
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter
```

Launching Jupyter, I get the following error:

```
(kmkplot) C:\Users\userabc>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\userabc\.conda\envs\kmkplot\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 9, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "C:\Users\userabc\.conda\envs\kmkplot\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\userabc\.conda\envs\kmkplot\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\userabc\.conda\envs\kmkplot\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\userabc\.conda\envs\kmkplot\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 86, in <module>
    from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
  File "C:\Users\userabc\.conda\envs\kmkplot\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

So, what I did was create a new environment kmkplot2 to test whether sqlite works:

```
conda create --name kmkplot
conda activate kmkplot2
```

Then test sqlite before installing Jupyter:

```
(kmkplot2) C:\Users\userabc>python
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>>
```

And it does.  So why is it breaking with Jupyter install?  Here's exactly what happens:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter
...
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
...
sqlite             conda-forge/win-64::sqlite-3.29.0-hfa6e2cd_0
...
```

Why would it install sqlite again if I already have it?  Could this be breaking itself?  Is there a way to prevent it installing sqlite?

```
Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Downloading and Extracting Packages
terminado-0.8.2      | 22 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
wheel-0.33.4         | 52 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
setuptools-41.0.1    | 658 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
pywinpty-0.5.5       | 46 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
notebook-6.0.0       | 7.2 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
jsonschema-3.0.1     | 103 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
certifi-2019.6.16    | 149 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: | b'Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extension...\n      - Validating: ok\n'
done 

(kmkplot2) C:\Users\userabc>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\userabc\.conda\envs\kmkplot2:
...
sqlite                    3.29.0               hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
...

(kmkplot2) C:\Users\userabc>python
Python 3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul  1 2019, 22:01:29) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlite'

>>> exit()

(kmkplot2) C:\Users\userabc>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\userabc\.conda\envs\kmkplot2\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 9, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "C:\Users\userabc\.conda\envs\kmkplot2\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\userabc\.conda\envs\kmkplot2\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\userabc\.conda\envs\kmkplot2\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\userabc\.conda\envs\kmkplot2\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 86, in <module>
    from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
  File "C:\Users\userabc\.conda\envs\kmkplot2\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

Any ideas what to try next?

Answer (score 0):

Upon reviewing my question text above, I noticed that the Python version reported was 2.7.x but after Jupyter install was 3.7.x so I forced Python version 3.4.3 (just because I know that is a version and now Jupyter is starting after re-install of Jupyter.  I'm still getting some other errors but this specific question can be closed.